# monaco-editor – Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.(8010)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

I can't get why monaco-editor can't work with typescript files.

Here is the source code I passed into the editor:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Test.scss';

export const Test = (foo: number) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>Test</div>
    );
}
```

And the options:

Language = `typescript`
+

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
      target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.Latest,
      allowNonTsExtensions: true,
      moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
      module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
      noEmit: true,
      esModuleInterop: true,
      jsx: monaco.languages.typescript.JsxEmit.React,
      reactNamespace: "React",
      allowJs: true,
      typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"],
    });
```

So I told the editor "here is a typescript file", but that `foo: number` show error `Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.(8010)`

How to deal with it?

P.S. It's a web application, i.e. monaco-editor is not inside VS code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the language to "typescript". All the settings you have here are on top of the base language (e.g. JSX support, script target, module resolution etc.).

To set a language use either `editor.setModelLanguage(yourModel, "typescript");` (if the model exists already, e.g. the default one in the editor) or create your own model and specify the language in the creation call: `editor.createModel(content, language, uri);`.

Check `ITextModel.getModeId();` to see if it uses the correct language.

Comment: Created a model, set it using `editor.setModel`, and checked type using `model.getModeId()`, and there is `typescript` with the same result. So it's typescript with error 8010 (it's not a typescript file). If I remove `setCompilerOptions` typescript file works, but JSX (TSX) is not supported. So I think it's related to compiler options, but it's weird, because how TSC options can make typescript source to be not typescript?

Comment: Make sure you're setting the URI to something like `file:///a.ts`, I found that without it set correctly I got the error even if the language was set to `typescript`